# Apache Airflow - 1.10.4 - logging_mixin.py - Printing ASCII characters on logs

Tags: airflow

I'm receiving strange characters from {logging_mixin.py} :

```
[2019-08-15 22:06:57,130] {{logging_mixin.py:95}} INFO - [[34m2019-08-15 22:06:57,129[0m] {[34mbase_hook.py:[0m84} INFO[0m - Using connection to: [1mid: winrm_uat. Host: pgi-ms-wadmtm02.mgmt.msci.org, Port: None, Schema: None, Login:
```

This was produced after update from 1.10.3 to 1.10.4.

I haven't changed anything from Dockerfile related to LC :

```
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_CTYPE en_US.UTF-8
ENV LC_MESSAGES en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 4):

This was produced because of [[AIRFLOW-5065]](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5681) Add colors to console log #5681, which it is suppose to add colored logs only if stdout is console , but this is also reflected on UI .

I've disable this option on airflow.cfg :

colored_console_log = False

Comment: Seems it was fixed but I think it's not released to any version yet https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/6046

Comment: Woop my bad, I can see the commit in 1.10.6 actually